# A Hilbert-style proof that $\Gamma \vdash A \Rightarrow \Gamma \vdash B \Longleftrightarrow \Gamma \vdash A \to B$

Tags: proof-explanation, propositional-calculus, hilbert-calculus

The Hilbert-style system I am using consists of the following axioms:

> 1. $\phi \to (\psi \to \phi)$
> 2. $\phi \to (\psi \to \xi) \to ((\phi \to \psi) \to (\phi \to \xi))$
> 3. $(\neg\phi \to \psi) \to (\neg\phi \to \neg\psi) \to \phi$

and modus ponens

> - $\Gamma \vdash \phi \Rightarrow \Gamma \vdash \phi \to \psi \Rightarrow \psi$.

I would like to prove the following metatheorem (call it 'implication metatheorem'):

> **Implication metatheorem.** $\qquad \Gamma \vdash A \Rightarrow \Gamma \vdash B \quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad \Gamma \vdash A \to B$

I already have a proof of the ($\Leftarrow$) direction (which is trivial), but I got stuck on the ($\Rightarrow$) step. My guess is that we need to use the deduction metatheorem and show that $\Gamma, A \vdash B$ holds if any derivation of $A$ from a set of assumptions $\Gamma$ gives a derivation of $B$ from $\Gamma$. This is very intuitive, but now I can't come up with a precise argument that shows that $\Gamma, A \vdash B$ must be the case!

**Edit:**

My obvious first attempt was the following:

(i) assume the left-hand side of the equivalence: $\Gamma \vdash A \Rightarrow \Gamma \vdash B$,

(ii) assume $\Gamma$ and $A$ as hypothesis,

(iii) derive $A$,

(iv) derive $B$ using the left-hand side of the equivalence.

but on closer inspection I noticed that the strategy in (iv) has a fatal flaw: what we accomplish is just a derivation of $\Gamma,A \vdash A$, so we cannot use the left-hand side of the equivalence unless we know that $A \in \Gamma$, or a means of reducing it to a derivation of $\Gamma \vdash A$. In other words, that would be to assume the stronger lemma
$$\Gamma \vdash A \Rightarrow \Gamma\vdash B \quad\Longrightarrow\quad \Gamma, C \vdash A \Rightarrow \Gamma, C\vdash B$$ but I don't know how to prove that either (is it even true?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $\Rightarrow$ direction you want to prove **does not hold**.

As a counterexample, let $A$ and $B$ be different propositional variables, and let $\Gamma$ be empty.

Then $\varnothing\vdash A \Rightarrow \varnothing\vdash B$ is true (because $\varnothing\vdash A$ and $\varnothing\vdash B$ are both false), but $\varnothing\vdash A\to B$ is false.

---

The metatheorem that does hold is:
$$ \Gamma, A \vdash B \iff \Gamma \vdash A \to B $$
whose $\Rightarrow$ direction is the (nontrivial) [*Deduction Theorem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deduction_theorem).

Comment: Suppose that $\Gamma$ is ∅.  Suppose that A is true, and B is true also.  Then $\Gamma$, A $\vdash$ B abbreviates (∅ U {A}) $\vdash$ B or equivalently {A} $\vdash$ B.  That holds true.  But, if the empty set doesn't imply anything, then $\Gamma$ $\vdash$ (A $\rightarrow$ B) is false, since that's just ∅ $\vdash$ (A $\rightarrow$ B) in other notation.  So, the same reasoning used here leads to the Deduction Meta-Theorem failing.  Thus, I can't see this answer as correct.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood: (1) We're talking about provability here -- propositional variables have no inherent notion of being true or false, and proofs are conducted without committing to any particular value assignment for them. So "suppose $A$ is true" is not a meaningful statement. (2) $A\vdash B$ is _not_ true. (3) The empty set entails lots of things; for example $\varnothing\vdash A\to A$ holds.

Comment: On second thought I think your answer is correct and my previous comment was in error.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much! :D